# CSS: preventing div container to scale or stretch

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigator for my website which has 5 buttons: Button1-4 and background-image as Button5.

If you maximize your browser window with width and scale it down by height only, `1280x300` for example, you will see that div containers background is off from the buttons, which looks terrible, see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4bm2kxxj/embedded/result/).

By my research, i have tried every possible options which didn't seem to work, div `menu` style:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block; /* did not work */
    overflow: auto; /* did not work */
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 3%;
    z-index:99;
    max-height: 15%; /* non of these below worked. */
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 15%;
    min-width: 100%; 
}
```

Why is it stretching down with window even when it exceeds its `max` and `min` width? How can i avoid my div menu to stretch and scale with browser? What are the options with css?

[Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/4bm2kxxj/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `min-height` in pixels instead of percent. Since you are already specifying `height` and `max-height` in percent, your layout can afford the `min-height` in pixels.
For sake of a demo, I used `100px` as `height`

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/4bm2kxxj/3/

CSS:

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  z-index: 99;
  max-height: 15%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px; /*can be any other value*/
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a div container from streching, when defining the width and height, don't use %, because this means that the width and height of the div is changed based on the width and height of the browser window. Use px instead, and you should not have such issues.

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 3%;
    z-index:99;
}`
```

This should work.
You can see the changes here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4bm2kxxj/4/

The same thing could be done with the buttons as well, give the margins, width and height px values instead of % values;

This should solve the problem.

A good Idea would be to use media queries in your code to change the css of the elements when a specific condition is true.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Or frameworks like Bootstrap, where everything is pre-made and all you have to do is learn how to use it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/4bm2kxxj/2/

Add this line:

```
  overflow:hidden;
```

to the menu class

Comment: I have tried that too, but that would simply hide all elements in menu, div is still being scaled and stretched.